Undefined control sequence. \sf@counterlist
I am getting the error

Undefined control sequence. The compiler is having trouble
understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is
spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you
have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
 \sf@counterlist
l.93 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
(e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

which happens on the line of \begin{document}. Does anybody have an idea what it could be? Below is an MWE of my preamble.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[affil-it, auth-sc]{authblk}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsthm}  % For theorem-like environments and proof environment
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\newcommand\fnsep{\textsuperscript{,}}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalfont \itshape \small}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ulem}
\renewcommand\Authsep{}
\renewcommand\Authand{}
\renewcommand\Authands{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

%\makeatletter
%\newlength{\fnBreite}
%\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
%  \settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
%  \protect\footnotesize\upshape%
%  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\columnwidth}\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\fnBreite}%
%  \makebox[\fnBreite][l]{\@thefnmark.\phantom{}}%
%  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\everypar{\hspace*{1em}}\hspace*{-1em}\upshape#1}}
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixsection}{ m }{
    \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix\ \csname the##1\endcsname\quad}
    \section{#1}
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}[theorem]{Hypothesis}

\newcommand{\tablewidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newcommand{\widetablewidth}{\textwidth}

\definecolor{myauthor}{RGB}{0,120,0}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=myauthor]{hyperref} 

%\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\title{A particularly nice title \thanks{Thank you}}

\author[1]{Albert Einstein \textsuperscript{\textcircled{r}}}

\affil[1]{Somewhere}

\date{\today \\}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent This paper does something extraordinary.
 
\vspace{1em}

\noindent \textbf{JEL Codes:} afasfas \\
\noindent \textbf{Keywords:} dsgh \\  
\end{abstract}

\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{page}{0}
\newpage


\section{Introduction}
\end{document}


do you really need all those packages to show the error? You should minimise your example to make it more reasonable for peopel to trace

A more reasonable example that could have been posted is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document} and as described in the linked answersubfigandsubcaption` are offering the same functionality it can not work to load both.

You are right, and thanks for still pointing out the answer!
